# Emotion with Jest: Cannot find module 'react'

Tags: reactjs, emotion

I just set up `@emotion/react` with `create-react-app`.  The UI works fine, but when running `jest`, I'm getting this error:

> `Cannot find module 'react' from '../node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-react.cjs.dev.js'`

I've tried:

- Make sure `react` package is in package.json
- Delete `node-modules` and re-run `yarn`
- Update file directive to `/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */`
- Install `@testing-library/react`
- Install `react-test-renderer`
- Install `@emotion/jest`

No luck.  Any idea why this might be happening?

Just importing from Emotion throws this error, but only with the JSX directive and import statements together.  Just one or the other does not throw the error.  Changing `{ jsx }` to `{ css }` also causes the issue not to reproduce.

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx } from "@emotion/react";
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the dependencies were in the wrong project - we have a server project and a child project which is the React app.  I had some Emotion dependencies in the top-level project which made the app work correctly but Jest fail for some reason.

Moving all Emotion dependencies to the correct location - the Create React App project - fixed the issue.